# Security when uploading images with Carrierwave

Tags: security, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, pundit

I'm using carrierwave for upload images. 
And I saw how to configuring file permissions like this:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0666
  config.directory_permissions = 0777
  config.storage = :file
end
```

But I don't understand what is this permissions. 
Can anybody help me with this question?
And I'm doing a post with an attachment for an image. 
So is a problem of security to upload the images on the public folder?
Because i'm using restrictions with the gem Pundit for restrict the access to the Posts. But I notice who anyone with the link can see the image(post.attachment).
What I need to do for restrict completely the access? 
Can anyone help me with this? I will appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0777` is UNIX shorthand for something with read/write/execute turned on, something that means the directory is public.

`0666` is shorthand for read/write, meaning the files are able to be read and modified by anyone.

These values are in [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) because of the leading `0`, something that makes it easier to express specific bit patterns.